# Android. BottomNavigationView with single activity approach

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, bottomnavigationview

What is the best wayto use bottomNavigationView with single activity approach.
I found examples with Navigation Architecture Component but i don't want to use Navigation Component.

For example, I have one activity and 3 fragments for the bottomNavigationView, the other 6 fragments should not include the menu. Here is my bottom navigation view:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

What should I do right, add the menu only in three fragments, where it is necessary, or add a menu to the activity and hide it if a fragment is displayed where the menu is not needed? Please help me figure it out)

Answer (score 1):

First create menu items and By using bottom navigation listener we attach fragment based on the  menu item in swith case

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.xx:
                    
                case R.id.xx:
               
                case R.id.xx:
                
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```